What does it mean when a Pokemon's level is red?
What does it mean when a Pokemon's level number is red instead of white?

Image from PokeRogue: An Increasingly Hard Roguelike Pokemon Game by RTGame

According to Reddit, the level turns red when the Pokemon has reached the level cap for that floor.

Level caps are usually increments of 6-10 levels depending on the floors. If you hit a level cap, the level number turns red. You can’t gain experience naturally beyond that until the cap is raised. You CAN bypass this and go further by giving rare candy to something at the cap.
There is no penalty for reaching the cap.

